# Prevent tensorflow from taking up the entire gpu when using Monitored Training Session

Tags: tensorflow, distributed

I am trying to use distributed Tensorflow.
How do I prevent tensorflow from occupying entire Gpu, in Monitored Training Session ? Currently I am using Allow_Gpu_Growth=True. But it does not work